# PHP o MySQL encontrar valor maximo numerico de una columna

Tags: php, mysql

Me encuentro con una pequeña duda a la hora intentar obtener el valor máximo de entre una columna en especial de una tabla en una base de datos MySQL.

Por ejemplo supongamos que en una tabla de una BD tengo una columna llamada favoritos, sus valores son tipo numérico (Esto debido a que cada entrada o fila en la posición favoritos almacena la cantidad de personas que han puesto en favoritos ese elemento en especifico).

Yo lo que haría entonces para encontrar el valor máximo entre la columna de favoritos sería hacer algo como:

```
SELECT favoritos FROM mytabla WHERE favoritos > 0;
```

Y luego haría un fetch de los resultados en php, luego crearía una variable que almacenara el mayor valor entre todos esos datos y recorrería cada uno de los resultados y guardaría en esa variable el resultado del mayor valor entre ellos.

El problema es que en una base de datos que ya tiene buena cantidad de contenido no creo que esto sea muy eficiente, ¿PHP o mysql tiene alguna manera de hacer esto mas eficiente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql nos permite hacer muchas consultas que nos pueden ayudar a conseguir esos valores entre ellos el máximo de una columna que tiene valores numéricos, podrias hacer algo asi.

```
$query="(SELECT MAX(numero) as maximo) FROM $tabla";
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, por cierto, y para hacerlo alrevez?, seria MIN en vez de max cierto?, es decir el valor minimo.

Comment: si apartir de la logica el lenguage sql puede hacer diferentes cosas como contar sumar ejemplo :  (count - max - min - sum - avg)